# How can I get the value of a key in this associative array

Tags: php, mysql

I have a CMS I am using that serializes their data in the database. I used the unserialize() function to convert the data into an associative array. Now I am having a hard time pulling the value of the image from the associative array:

This is the simple while loop I am using to loop through the rows:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_models)){

    $model_name = $row['ModelName'];
    $model_thumbnail = unserialize($row['info']);

}
```

this is the Key and Value of the array I need to get the value of, so I can assign the correct thumbnail image to the respected person:

["1x_filename"]=> string(19) "00/83/83-set-1x.jpg"

The full array is below, and the key I am targeting is located more at the bottom of this array:

```
array(1) { 
    ["thumbs"]=> array(2) { 
        [16]=> array(17) { 
            ["id"]=> string(2) "82" 
            ["1x_width"]=> string(3) "220" 
            ["1x_height"]=> string(3) "330" 
            ["2x_width"]=> string(3) "440" 
            ["2x_height"]=> string(3) "660" 
            ["3x_width"]=> string(3) "660" 
            ["3x_height"]=> string(3) "990" 
            ["4x_width"]=> string(3) "880" 
            ["4x_height"]=> string(4) "1320" 
            ["width"]=> string(3) "220" 
            ["height"]=> string(3) "330" 
            ["retinamode"]=> string(1) "1" 
            ["filename"]=> string(10) "82-set.jpg" 
            ["1x_filename"]=> string(19) "00/82/82-set-1x.jpg"
            ["2x_filename"]=> string(19) "00/82/82-set-2x.jpg"
            ["3x_filename"]=> string(19) "00/82/82-set-3x.jpg"
            ["4x_filename"]=> string(19) "00/82/82-set-4x.jpg" 
        } 
        [17]=> array(17) { 
            ["id"]=> string(2) "83" 
            ["1x_width"]=> string(3) "106" 
            ["1x_height"]=> string(3) "150" 
            ["2x_width"]=> string(3) "212" 
            ["2x_height"]=> string(3) "300" 
            ["3x_width"]=> string(3) "318" 
            ["3x_height"]=> string(3) "450" 
            ["4x_width"]=> string(3) "424" 
            ["4x_height"]=> string(3) "600" 
            ["width"]=> string(3) "106" 
            ["height"]=> string(3) "150" 
            ["retinamode"]=> string(1) "1" 
            ["filename"]=> string(10) "83-set.jpg" 
            ["1x_filename"]=> string(19) "00/83/83-set-1x.jpg" 
            ["2x_filename"]=> string(19) "00/83/83-set-2x.jpg" 
            ["3x_filename"]=> string(19) "00/83/83-set-3x.jpg" 
            ["4x_filename"]=> string(19) "00/83/83-set-4x.jpg"
        } 
    } 
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Add it as a code like this is very hard to see anything

Comment: The `{}` button can automatically format stuff like this by indenting it with four spaces.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like this :

```
$model_thumbnail = unserialize($row['info']);
$picturePath = $model_thumbnail['thumbs'][17]['1x_filename'];
```

picturePath will contain your images path

Comment: You nailed it brother, thanks! Where did the 17 come from?

Comment: @SuperKenCodes The 17 is within your array. Its hard to say what it is for. I assume it is some kind of user ID or maybe declares a version for your data. Your array has 16 and 17 in your given case, where the rest of the data is saved below.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use mysqli or an other database adapter in php, as mysql_ functions are depricated and even removed in never php versions. But according to your code, you could simply use a foreach loop to get your data.

Your results gives back some kind of data groups, I assume those are the user ids or something similar. It could also be the version or something like it. As I do not know that here are two possible ways

Get all:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_models)){

    $model_name = $row['ModelName'];
    $model_thumbnail = unserialize($row['info']);
    // echo all 1x_filename values from all given "ids"
    foreach ($model_thumbnail['thumbs'] as $model_id => $model_values) {
        print $model_values['1x_filename'];
    }

}
```

Get only the latest id, in case those are for some kind of versioning:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_models)){

    $model_name = $row['ModelName'];
    $model_thumbnail = unserialize($row['info']);

    // sort array, so highest ID (assume-ably the newest)
    krsort($model_thumbnail['thumbs']);

    // get array entry
    $firstEntry = reset($model_thumbnail['thumbs']);
    print  $firstEntry['1x_filename'];

}
```